# How to get items of a user within a specific folder using ArcGIS REST API

Tags: arcgis-rest-api

I am trying to get items of a specific folder using the ArcGIS REST API. Reading through the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/user-content.htm) all it says for `https://[root]/content/users/[username]` is:

> The user content resource returns information on the user's owned items. A user's content are items either in their root content folder (e.g. /content/users/) or in a subfolder of the home folder with the given folder ID.

In addition there are example responses for specific subfolder. But I cannot find any request example to retrieve items for a specific folder.

Looking at the response example, I understand that each response is limited to **one** folder (root folder or subfolder). I also haven't found any parameters in the [Common Parameters](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/common-parameters.htm).

And looking at the list of endpoints on the left side of the [documentation](https://developers.arcgis.com/rest/users-groups-and-items/user-content.htm), I only find two endpoints using the `folderID`:

[image]

But none that retrieves items... there is no endpoint `https://[root]/content/users/[username]/[folderID]` documented.

Did I miss something in the documentation? How can I retrieve items of a user within a specific folder using ArcGIS REST API?

(I ultimately want to test if a user has at least 1 item because I want to enhance a User object with a property `hasItems`. Sadly the endpoint `https://[root]/community/users/[userName]` doesn't provide such information out of the box.)

---

**Edit:** I found a solution for my ultimate goal to test if a user has at least 1 item using the endpoint `https://[root]/search`:

```
https://[root]/search?f=json&filter=owner:"[username]"&num=1&token=[token]
```

However, I would still be interested in how to retrieve items of a user within a specific folder using ArcGIS REST API.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess I should just have tested `https://[root]/content/users/[username]/[folderID]`. **It is an undocumented endpoint** as of November 8, 2023.